# What does a + function() { } notation do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading a javascript file written by someone that has a couple of functions for modifying CSS and other things and I am not a pro level at Javascipt; I am seeing a piece of code like

```
    + function(a) {
    "use strict";

    function b() {
        var a = document.createElement("bootstrap"),
            b = {
                WebkitTransition: "webkitTransitionEnd",
                MozTransition: "transitionend",
                OTransition: "oTransitionEnd otransitionend",
                transition: "transitionend"
            };
        for (var c in b)
            if (void 0 !== a.style[c]) return {
                end: b[c]
            }
    }
    a.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = function(b) {
        var c = !1,
            d = this;
        a(this).one(a.support.transition.end, function() {
            c = !0
        });
        var e = function() {
            c || a(d).trigger(a.support.transition.end)
        };
        return setTimeout(e, b), this
    }, a(function() {
        a.support.transition = b()
    })
}(window.jQuery), + function(a) {
```

What does adding the + sign do to a javascript function ? The code is really long so I just pasted whatever i thought was relevant.

I have found my answer and this is a duplicate post of another but for those who want the full source code it is here 
[source code](http://randbresearch.co.uk/assets/js/scripts.min.js?ver=2a3e700c4c6e3d70a95b00241a845695)

Comment: If these functions are returning some integers, maybe it's adding all values of functions?

Comment: can you give the link to source? It'd be more helpful

Comment: This does not seem like enough information as it ends in the middle of the script.

Comment: It's a unary operator. [It could as well be any other unary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7587056/1048572).

Comment: It does an arithmetic operation which is resulting in NaN. The complete source would be helpful. A '+' is often used before function _calls_ to cast the return value to number. Example: `+ new Date()`

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov: That is what certain minifiers do to reduce code size. In face, this whole script looks like a pretty-printed minified script, given all the one-letter variable names.

Comment: for those of you who are looking for the source code, here it is http://randbresearch.co.uk/assets/js/scripts.min.js?ver=2a3e700c4c6e3d70a95b00241a845695

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov It's propably minified code that got prettified.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, I see, yeah I should've assumed :) You must be right.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov it is a minified code that got prettified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at this other question ([JavaScript plus sign in front of function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name)) on the same subject, the following seems to be the answer:

> It forces the parser to treat the part following the + as an
>   expression. This is usually used for functions that are invoked
>   immediately

source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13341710/970847

Comment: Thanks, I'll can read up on this now. I googled for answers but couldnt find an answer. So it is an IIFE; thats all.

Comment: Please [vote to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) the question as a duplicate (or flag it for mod attention), instead of posting the link as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> It forces the parser to treat the part following the + as an
>   expression. This is usually used for functions that are invoked
>   immediately.

From here [JavaScript plus sign in front of function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name)

Comment: Please [vote to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) the question as a duplicate (or flag it for mod attention), instead of posting the link as an answer.