# Why does Twitter use the !function syntax in their embed code

Tags: javascript

I was looking at Twitter's embedded code and saw that they are using `!function`. While I know that this evaluates to false, I was wondering what the point of it was.

Here is the code I am referring to:

```
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Comment: nah ... I know what it does ... I want to know *why* they are doing it

Comment: The second answer there explains why. Granted, the title of the question is a bit unfortunate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's to save a byte.  It's the shortest way to invoke the function.  The alternative would have been:

```
(function(){...})();
```

Note the syntax Twitter uses:

```
!function(){...}(params);
```

Which means that they have decreased the length to invoke a function by one byte.

EDIT: Just an after thought: It also makes it very clear that you are invoking the anonymous function.

Comment: if that is so... !function(){ console.log("foo") } would log foo .. but it does not

Comment: See my edit, `!function(){console.log("foo")}();` should work.

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have guessed that. Do you know why it no longer requires parentheses?

Comment: @skier88: The reason why it works is described fully as the second answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function .

Comment: Thanks. I was actually just reading that, and it kind of dodges the issue (though it explains everything I already know pretty well :p ). Maybe a better way of asking would be, why doesn't `function() {}();` work?

Comment: Actually, never mind, one of the comments on that post answered it. Apparently javascript parsers mistake it for a function declaration if it's the first thing on a line.