# !function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

I am looking at the bootstrap Javascript provided by the `Bootstrap, from Twitter`.

And the first thing I notice in the file is `!function( $ )`
What is the purpose of `!` in front of the function here?

Also notice the `end:` what is that for?

Here is the actual code block, incase you are interested:

```
!function( $ ) {

  $(function () {

    "use strict"

    /* CSS TRANSITION SUPPORT (https://gist.github.com/373874)
     * ======================================================= */

    $.support.transition = (function () {
      var thisBody = document.body || document.documentElement
        , thisStyle = thisBody.style
        , support = thisStyle.transition !== undefined || thisStyle.WebkitTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MozTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.MsTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.OTransition !== undefined

      return support && {
        end: (function () {
          var transitionEnd = "TransitionEnd"
          if ( $.browser.webkit ) {
            transitionEnd = "webkitTransitionEnd"
          } else if ( $.browser.mozilla ) {
            transitionEnd = "transitionend"
          } else if ( $.browser.opera ) {
            transitionEnd = "oTransitionEnd"
          }
          return transitionEnd
        }())
      }
    })()

  })
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function

Comment: Look especially at the second answer on that page, and compare the `!` technique to the `()` technique used in the `end` property definition.

Comment: The `end:` is simply a key in an object literal (notice the `{` at the end of the line before it).