# What does !function (name, definition) means in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

So the start of the [morpheus](https://github.com/ded/morpheus) script has this:

```
!function (name, definition) {
  if (typeof define == 'function') define(definition)
  else if (typeof module != 'undefined') module.exports = definition()
  else this[name] = definition()
}('morpheus', function () {
```

why is there a `!` there?

Comment: It was answered before, look at this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function

Comment: Great explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function