# Why put negation before immediate anonymous function invocation

Tags: javascript, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

I saw this in [bootstrap-dropdown.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js)

```
!function ($) {
   "use strict"; // jshint ;_;
   ...
}(window.jQuery);
```

what is the reason behind this bang (negation) before immediate anonymous function invocation?

Comment: So it executes, otherwise it's just a function declaration. -- See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function