# Javascript in bootstrap api...what does the ! mean

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

At the beginning of the bootstrap.js code file they have this

```
!function($) {
```

what does it mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function

Comment: Yeah it looks like it is a copy of that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you code this: `function something() {something}`, it's a declaration of a function, but it does not invoke the function (you'd have to run `something()` later on).

So, to actually invoke the function, you need to do something like `(function(){})();` ...  "`!function($) {}`" is sort of an alternative to the wrapping the entire function in parens.  The exclamation mark syntax is a shortcut to writing that. "!" turns the line into an expression that returns `true`.