# Why use NOT operator on anonymous function call? (a la Knockout 2.1.0)

Tags: javascript, iife

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

If you look at the [source code for KnockoutJS 2.1.0](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js) you will see a code structure like this start on line 7:

```
!function(factory) { ... }(factoryDefinition);
```

The not operator causes this expression to evaluate to `true` rather than `undefined`, but why bother?

Comment: Yes, it appears I have the same question as the "exclamation mark" question. Apologies, I didn't notice it in my search.

Comment: @CgodLEY: StackOverflow's search doesn't do so well with punctuation and other symbols. Helps a bit to spell it out.

Comment: You use it to provoke immediate invocation of the function by making it look like an expression and not statement.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is a concise way to form an immediately executed function expression.

Traditionally, people have used these two forms

```
(function(){ }()); // Recommended by Crockford
(function(){ })(); // What most people use
```

If you try to just use

```
function(){ }(); // Syntax error
```

it will be a syntax error, because it is interpreted as a function declaration rather than an expression. This is why you would need to wrap the function in parentheses.

But if you put a unary operator before the function declaration, you don't have to add a cosing parentheses, and it chops off one character of the code, which is a (very) tiny performance benefit. There are several unary operators that can be used for this same purpose

```
!function(){ }();
~function(){ }(); 
-function(){ }(); 
+function(){ }();
```

Answer (score 3):

Because if you don't do *something* then it looks like a syntax error:

```
function(factory) { ... }(factoryDefinition);
```

Try it.

It's necessary to get the parser to a point where it expects an expression, so that the `function` keyword is recognized in that context. Otherwise, when the parser sees `function` as the first token in a statement, it expects a simple function declaration, and that can't be followed by a parenthesized argument list.

There are various alternatives, around each of which cluster various opinions.

Comment: I tried the following expression on NodeJS and it seemed just fine, am I missing something? `function(message){console.log(message)}('hello');` result: `hello`

Comment: @CgodLEY That doesn't work in my Node console... (The output is `...`)

Comment: No, Node gives me a syntax error. (In fact I get it at the open paren in the function declaration, because a function declaration without a function name is erroneous.

Comment: Ah, I didn't put the semi-colon and that caused it to work somehow, try this: `function(message){console.log(message)}('hello')`

Comment: @CgodLEY: You should probably consider that a bug in the REPL. It won't work in your normal code.

Comment: @amnotiam Yes, I'm not sure why it's working :)

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for the answer. Looking back I think you understood why the problem was occurring but it didn't click for me until I saw some concrete examples of the various alternatives.