# Why does this Twitter script tag try to evaluate to true? Does it matter?

Tags: javascript, twitter, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

I'm maintaining an existing site with a "tweet" button, which appears to come from [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)

A colleague here brought up a great question: Why does this script tag reverse the (`undefined` via no return statement) value of this self-calling function? (pretty-fied for ease of reading, original is at link)

```
<script>
  !function(d,s,id) {
//^--- that
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id)) {
      js=d.createElement(s);
      js.id=id;
      js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
  }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

To my non-JS-pro eyes, that appears to be flipping the boolean value of `undefined`, thereby allowing the entire `<script>` tag to evaluate to true. For what it's worth, that is a totally foreign idea to me (that `<script>` tag has an expression value).

My expectation is that there is some specific browser out there for which a `<script>` tag's *boolean value* (yes, I feel crazy even typing that) matters.

So the basic question is this: **Does a `<script>` have a meaningful "expression" value to any browsers you know of?** and **What is the implicit meaning of a true vs. false in this case?**

Comment: @Quentin, Could you post a quick answer pointing to the other question? I don't think this is quite an exact duplicate: I was under the impression that the value of the guts of a `<script>` tag might (in some crazy circumstance) matter. I would like to accept your answer if it specifically calls out that misunderstanding (e.g. "No, `<script>` tags do not have meaningful expression value to browsers").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An explanation of what is going on and why...

In Javascript, you have `function statements` and `function expressions`.  The two of them are similar, but not exact.

**Function statement**

```
function myTest() {return true;}
```

**Function Expressions**

```
var f = function() {return true;}
alert(f()); //

alert(function() { return true}); // Return value is used

// and even

(function(x, y) {
  var z, x; // private variables, hidden from the outside scope
  var r = x  + y;
  // Return value is ignored.
}(1, 2));

// The ! can be used to start a function expression too.
// This is totally legal Javascript, but it isn't in the normal
// "vernacular" of the langage
!function(x, y) {
  var z, z1; // Private vars
  // Do something with side effects
  // Return value is ignored.
}(x, y);
```

**Updated due to comments**

```
//The following code works identical:
var v1 = (function(a, b) {return a+b}(1,2));
var v2 = (function(a, b) {return a+b})(1,2);
var v3 = function(a, b) {return a+b}(1,2)
```

I prefer the first form because it lets me use the block matching tools on my editor, and the `f1` form is preferred by the sometimes useful programs [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) and [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/).

All create a function expression and then invoke it immediately.  In *this* case, the parens are not needed by the Javascript compiler, but they serve as a very useful hint to the reader that this is not a normal assignment.

On the other hand, you must have *something* to tell the JS engine that you have a function expression instead of a function statement.  The `=` sign above works, but when there is no assignment, you need to start off with some kind of operator, be it `(+!`

```
!function(x, y) {alert(x, y)}(1, 2);
```

The leading operator makes it an *expression*.  The `()` in the above examples force it to an expression as well.

Comment: In your middle example, do you have the closing parens mixed up? I suspect it's supposed to be `})(1, 2);` instead of `}(1, 2));`

Comment: @ctrahey -- Lightly  updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: +1 thanks. If @Quentin does not post an answer, this will be accepted. (his comment was posted 4 minutes after my question, I'm sure you understand :-)

Comment: Understood.  I post to answer questions, not to win points ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a new script tag and adds it before the first element of type script if there's no script element with id `twitter-wjs`.

Since `!` is the NOT operator in Javascript, it evaluates to `true` when its operand can be converted to `false` (in this case, when no element with id `twitter-wjs` exists, `document.getElementById("twitter-wjs")` returns `undefined`, and this in Javascript is a falsey value so the result in conjunction with `!` operator will be `true` and the block of code inside the `if` gets executed. Any object in Javascript will be `true` when checking for its boolean value (try doing `!![Object]` and you will prove it), so the `if` block won't be executed when any element is returned by `document.getElementById()`.

UPDATE:
Regarding to your comments, I see @JeremyJStarcher answer is ok, but I am adding something:
In your code you have a `function expression`. for `function expressions` an identifier is not needed. But when executing, the Javascript interpreter may confuse and think of it as a `function declaration`. In `function declarations`, the identifier is not optional, and so the interpreter will throw a Syntax Error. For avoiding this, `!` operator is being used here so it will be treated as a `function expression`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think you've answered as though I was curious about the second `!`. Note that I am asking about flipping the return "of this self-calling function", and the question in general is scoped around truthyness of an entire `<script>` tag.

Comment: I have edited the question to make that more clear.