# What is this javascript syntax? !function(){}

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

I came across this today and have never seen before:

```
!function($) {
//contents removed

}( window.jQuery );
```

I am specifically wondering what the exclamation point does. Is there any documentation on it? Internet searches haven't yielded good results.

Thanks!

Comment: The `!` is negating the result of the function call.

Comment: It is the same as `!expr` where expr is `function() { .. }()` or an IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression. (The `!` is useless, but may exist to prevent the "accidental" omission of a semi-colon under ASI.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function May be helpful

Answer (score 3):

An  exclamation mark before a `function` statement creates a *function expression*. If you want to create a function which invokes itself, it *must be* an expression not a declaration.

One could achieve the same result by using a `+` character for instance, or putting the whole expression into parenthesis.

```
+function( $ ) {}( window.jQUery );
```

or

```
(function( $ ) {}( window.jQuery ));
```