# Self Invoking functions difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between these two self invoking functions? The function does not work if the `!` (not) symbol is added.

Please clarify if any one has clear understanding.

```
// first
(function( $ ) {
   // ...
})( jQuery );


// second
!function($){
    alert("test1");
}(jQuery), function(){
   alert("test2");
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: `function () {} function () {}`, remove `,` between functions bodies.

Comment: What do you mean by "the function does not work"? What about it doesn't work?

Comment: When I read "self invoking functions" I was kind of expecting recursive functions...

Comment: It seems like syntax mistake in the 2nd code: it contains self invoking function **and** anonymous function definition separated by comma

Comment: Can you please check this plugin jquery input mask - here this type of function is used. https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/blob/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129774/what-is-this-javascript-syntax-function

Answer (score -3):

1. `!function () {}` means `negative function` (similar to `if (!someVar) {}`), to make sure what result is before making it negative, function must be executed. So `!` can be replaced with `+`.
2. You have something wrong with *//second*, because you create two anonymous functions and between there is `,`. I think you are getting syntax error in this place, so next function does not work (and is not executed, because no one is calling this function)

Comment: [the comma, makes a sequence of *expressions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). So the second form works perfectly.. until you remove the `!` and turn the *expressions* that are there into (incomplete) *statements*