# How do I pass a variable to a ajax success function as it was at the time of the ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, scope

So this is my ajax call (pretty much standard jQuery but using the couchdb jquery library, http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js/ ):

```
var stuff = "some stuff";
$.couch.db("test_db").create({
    success: enyo.bind(this, function (data) {
        console.log(stuff);
    })
});
stuff = "a change in stuff";
```

And I'd like the output of console.log to be "some stuff" rather then "a change in stuff".

The more methods to do this the better, cause I think some methods might need me to not use "enyo.bind" ( http://enyojs.com/ ), but perhaps I can accomplish the same thing a little differently with those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function for it.

```
var create = function (stuff) {
  $.couch.db("test_db").create({
    success: enyo.bind(this, function (data) {
      console.log(stuff);
    })
  });
};

create(stuff);
```

Or, its equivalent as an anonymous function.

```
!function(stuff) {
  $.couch.db("test_db").create({
    success: enyo.bind(this, function (data) {
      console.log(stuff);
    })
  });
}(stuff);
```

See [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3755606/417685)

Answer (score 0):

You can "anchor" a variable by doing this:

```
(function(varname) {
    // code that relies on varname
})(varname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var stuff = "some stuff";
var callback = (function(stuff){ 
    return function(data){ console.log( stuff ) }; 
}(stuff));

$.couch.db("test_db").create({
    success: enyo.bind(this,  callback );
});
stuff = "a change in stuff";
```