# why there is a '!' before 'function($){}(window.jQuery)'?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

there is a "!" before function, why?

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js

```
! function($) {

    //......

}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Forces the function to be an expression, where the ending `(window.jQuery)` then invokes it.

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function

Comment: Just a visual clue to tell that's an IIFE, could as well be `~` or `+`. Unless a function returns something to a variable it won't matter. Most common practice is to wrap the whole expression in parentheses.

Comment: Asked many times already... please do some research before asking a question. This one should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` causes the function to be treated as an expression, meaning it has the same effect as this:

```
(function($) {

    //......

})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Well, not quite :p If you want to return a value, then `(...)()` is much better than `!`

Comment: It actually doesn't cause it to be evaluated... that's done by the parenthesis at the end.  It is just a way of indicating that it is invoked immediately.  It is for better readability (same as the parenthesis around the entire function)