# function syntax in bootstrap jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I was looking at `bootstrap.js` file and I noticed a *strange* (to me) notation for declare `function`s for **plugins**

Is there a difference between these two declaration:

```
function($)
```

and

```
function ($)
```

if it is not clear there is a blank char between `function` and `($)` in the second declaration. 
I'm wondering of this because **sublime text** gives me two different color on `($)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Comment: I asked another question too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it makes no difference.

JavaScript is mostly white space independent language, so apart from obvious cases (as in inside string or regex literals), and some not so obvious corner cases (multi-line return statements which sometimes break due to [ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)), indentation and white space does not change the outcome of your code.

It seems to be a bug with the ST highlighter, and my OCD side also dislikes having differently colored `$` signs in the code. `=]`