# what's mean: !function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple question.

I've found this code, and i don't know this statement

```
!function ($) {    
   // (...)
}(window.jQuery);
```

why put **!** before a function?

i've found this on bootstrap.js file, and i really want to know.

Thanks!

Comment: IIFE: `(function(){}()), !function(){}(), +function(){}(), ~function(){}()` ...

Comment: +function... also works, as does "0||"...

Answer (score 2):

It is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function) as nnnnnn mentioned. What the code is doing is executing the anonymous function while passing window.jQuery as a parameter, which will be referenced as $ inside the function. This allows the use of $ to reference jQuery without conflicting with any other library that might use the dollar sign.

This is a more readable version of the code:

```
(function($){
    // here, $ references jQuery and any variable or function 
    // declared here cannot be overridden outside of this function
})(window.jQuery)
```

Comment: Why is that more readable?

Comment: parens usually contribute to read-ability...

Answer (score -1):

The ! will always parse the statement as being true if the statement is not able to be parsed.

You can see this by using,

```
javascript:alert(!function(){}())
```

Where the resulting response is true

Comment: _"if the statement is not able to be parsed."_ - Huh? Ignoring for now that it is an expression, not a statement, what do you mean by "not able to be parsed"? Code that can't be parsed can't be executed...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Open up developer tools/firebug and try running `function() { alert('a'); }()` in there. It gives a syntax error. Now try `!function() { alert('a'); }()` -- it should alert and display `true`. Wrapping the function in parentheses also works. `(function(){ alert('a'); })()`