# Came across a convention I've never seen. What does it do? !function

Tags: javascript

I was just being goofy and analyzing some code in the source of some sites and I ran across this convention for an anonymous function.

```
!function(window){
     //so a bunch of stuff
}(this)
```

I have never seen the !function usage for an anonymous function. What does it do, and why would someone use it?

UPDATE2: my apologies, after additional testing, the following thread pretty much sums up its usage:

[What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Comment: dang, you are right. I did a search for various things like "!function" and nothing came up. thanks.

Comment: Wha, how can you **update** your question if you asked it 2 minutes ago?

Comment: well, meaning, before I posted I was still testing.. then figured some reason for it and decided to post it anyways figuring it might help someone else. So "I did" Have a question but I sorta figured out why, and posted anyways for future.

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong, by the way. It doesn't matter if `b` is defined or not.

Comment: It is better than the syntax convention douglas crawford calls "dog balls"

Comment: `!function(input){}(foo)` gives me foo is not defined. `(function(input){})(foo)` does also

Comment: ok. browser weirdness. i am getting error now too, and before I wasn't. must of been careless. my bad.