# JavaScript !function(){}

Tags: javascript, function, sizzle

when looking at the minified Sizzle code, I noticed that it begins like this:

```
!function(a){//...

  }(window)
```

Why is there an exclamation point at the beginning?

I thought that `!` was the `not` operator.

Thank you.

Edit:

[**Full Code**](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/dist/sizzle.min.js).

Comment: it IS the NOT operator. MInd to show the whole code? I guess this isn't a function declaration but rather an IIFE...

Comment: Are you sure that it's not something like `!function(){...return bool;}()`

Comment: @p.s.w.g: it shouldn't return boolean

Comment: Guess that's meant to be pseudo-code, but `true`or `false`would do better, yes.

Comment: For context, the code is [on github](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/dist/sizzle.min.js). If you understand what minification does, then I wouldn't question seemingly obscure syntax.

Comment: I don't understand why this question got a down vote.

Comment: @progo wasn't me, but most likely because you dind't specify the full code and, additionally, left out the most important part at the end - and the downvoter didn'T return after the edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
!function(a){/* ... */}();
```

Using an unary operator to invoke an IIFE is common practice. That's a common shorthand for:

```
(function(a){/* ... */}());
```

or:

```
(function(a){/* ... */})();
```

You can also substitute the not unary operator with any other unary operator:

```
-function(a){ /* ... */ }();
+function(a){ /* ... */ }();
/* ... etc. */
```

Comment: You mean `!function() {}()` doing `!function(){}` won't call it

Comment: yupp, you're missing the paranthesis at the end in your first line.

Comment: It's worth pointing out the function doesn't have a name.

Comment: Looks like there's also a performance increase to using bang functions: http://jsperf.com/bang-function

Comment: @megawac right, meant to do that. thanks for pointing that out ...

Comment: @remyabel Closures usually don't have one, and almost never when used as an IIFE. Actually, `(function Name () { ; }) ()`isn't valid, the "normal" funciton statement (`function name () { ; }`) most people use is just a shortcut for `var name = function () { ; }`.

Comment: @JohannesH.: Why shoudn't `(function Name () { ; }) ()` be valid? It is.

Comment: It is? Oh, well, I must admit, I never tested it. It isn't something I'd considered usefull yet. Well, then ignore that part of my comment. Rest stays valid though ;)

Comment: Please note that the `!` does not *invoke* the function. It's purpose is to make the parser treat the function definition like an expression, not a statement.

Comment: @JohannesH.: For function expressions, the name is optional (that's why it's omitted most of the time), for function declarations it is mandatory.

Comment: Hm. That does imply that `var func1 = function func2 () { ; }` assigns the function to `func1` as well as `func2`, and both are visible inside the current scope, doesn't it?

Comment: @JohannesH.: In older IE versions it does (it's a bug). The specification dictates that the name of a function *expression* is only visible within the function itself. It's great for debugging and recursive functions.

Comment: @JohannesH.: You're welcome! Good resource: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Comment: +1 But be wary of using the `+` and `-` operators for this since they're overloaded as binary operators as well. So if you omit a semicolon on the previous line, it can give an undesired result. The unary operators that are not overloaded are best, like `!`, `void`, `~`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

gives a good explaination for function invocation
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/44#issuecomment-13063933

```
!function () {}();
```

is equivalent to

```
(function(){})();
```

except the author is saving 1 byte of code.

In many cases, it's about saving bytes.

```
!function aaa(){}()
!function bbb(){}();
```

is the same as this:

```
!function aaa(){}()
;(function bbb(){})();
```

notice the ";" in that last bit. That is defensive, as it protects your code a bit from runaway js that might preceed it.

funny, I asked this same question some time ago:

[Came across a convention I've never seen. What does it do? !function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723574/came-across-a-convention-ive-never-seen-what-does-it-do-function)

great reference on it:
[What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Comment: Just for reference: in other programming languages, similar things are common. In bash scripts for example, the "do nothing command" (`:`) is often used to evaluate variable expansions.