# Javascript OOP, does not give me an error yet code does not work

Tags: javascript, oop

```
+ function Engine() {

    var createObject = function(elemClass, height, width){

        this.element = document.createElement('div');

        $(this.element).addClass(elemClass)
        $(this.element).css('height', height);
        $(this.element).css('width', width);

    };

    var box1 = new createObject('box', 200, 400);

    $('body').append(box1.element);

}();
```

Why does the following code provide no error? yet it also does not create the div within the body tag. Lets assume the body is empty. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why is there a unary operator in front of the function declaration?

Comment: Lack of an error message does not guarantee proper behavior.

Comment: @crush looks like an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Comment: Have you tried it with a debugger?

Comment: @crush: See [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3755606/1048572). It could be anything.

Comment: @crush - adding a `!`, `+`, `(` in front of the function makes it an IIFE

Comment: Oh, so he's saving a byte by making it slightly less obvious what is happening.

Comment: Seems obvious enough to me ?

Comment: My guess is that *is* adding the div, but since it has no content, you can't see it.  Your code seems to work for me (I added some CSS to make it ovbious): http://jsfiddle.net/2TA3f/

Comment: Seems like the element is added, but it's empty.

Comment: yes, its another way to do a IIFE

Comment: You probably did not wait until the DOM is ready to run that code. That's it. Get rid of the IIFE and wrap your code within `$(function () { ...});`

Comment: Seems that this style of IIFE is better suited for post-minification. Maybe I stand alone with that opinion. I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend on where in the page you put your script code.

if it is inside the `body` element, then the document already contains
a body element, `$('body')` return it and all work fine.

if it is in `head` element, the body does not exists yet at the time your script run, 
`$('body')` return an empty collection, and are appending the div into nothing.

You get no errors because jquery does not throw an error i this case.

If you want to write the script inside head element, wrap it in a document.ready call:

```
<script>
+ function Engine() {
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var createObject = function(elemClass, height, width){

            this.element = document.createElement('div');

            $(this.element).addClass(elemClass)
            $(this.element).css('height', height);
            $(this.element).css('width', width);

        };

        var box1 = new createObject('box', 200, 400);

        $('body').append(box1.element);

     });

}();
</script>
```

and it will work.

Comment: Awesome that works, thanks for the explanation as well! Just to clarify my code was in the head.

Comment: @user3229616 Please note that the IIFE is completely useless here. The function passed to `$(document).ready` already generates a new scope. Also if you are concerned about saving bytes, you can pass a function directly to `$()`, rather than calling `ready`.

Comment: @plalx great! I will take that into account, thanks for the note.

Comment: I agree, and it is even more concise if you put scripts at end of body element: you can even skip the $() because body element is already in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the following code provide no error?

Three possible reasons: The code didn't run, there is no error, or you did not see it. I'd guess the second.

> yet it also does not create the div within the body tag.

Maybe because there is no `<body>` element which could match your selector *at the time the code runs*. `$('body')` can be an empty collection and jQuery does not grump about it.

Have a look at [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572) for exact reason and some solutions, the easiest of which will be using [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3):

```
$(function Engine() {
    …
    $('body').append(box1.element);
});
```

Comment: That's one of the things I hate about jQuery. It advocates error swallowing.

Comment: @plalx: +1, however, warnings about empty collections can hardly be implemented in such a universal `$` function…

Comment: I do not mind an empty collection when I'm checking element existence only, but I do mind invoking certain operations on them. Perhaps they should have implemented the default `$` function to throw when empty and implement a second `$.query` function that doesn't...