# Javascript !function () {} notation

Tags: javascript

I've seen several times function like this

```
!function(self) {
    // code
}(this)
```

what means !function ?

Comment: Here is a good explanation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function

Comment: It's a short-hand for self-invoking anonymous functions, it's same as `(function(){
  // code
})();`