# Why does a ! before a function not return boolean opposite value?

Tags: javascript, iife

I was reading through [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755656/1252748). I sort of understand what's going on, but I'm confused why

```
!function foo() {
  console.log(true) ;
}()
```

doesn't return `false`.

> `!function () {}()` This will also return the boolean opposite of the
>   return value of the function, in this case true, because !undefined is
>   true. If you want the actual return value to be the result of the
>   call, then try doing it this way:

"will also return the boolean opposite" makes me think that `false` should be returned. Why isn't it. `alert(!true); //false`

Comment: because since the function doesnt return a value, `undefined` is returned, which is a falsy value, and the opposite of that is `true`

Comment: You already included the answer in your question: *"This will also return the boolean opposite of the return value of the function, **in this case true, because !undefined is true**."* The return value of the function is `undefined` because you don't return anything.

Comment: How does `!true` relate to `!function foo() {}()`? Were you thinking that the function itself was being negated instead of its return value after being invoked? Give it different return values and you'll see the difference. `return false` ... `return true` ... `return 0` ... etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a `return` statement the function returns `undefined`. When you apply `!` to `undefined` you get `true`.

Try

```
console.log(!function() { return true; }());
```

Note that the idiomatic use of `!` before an IIFE is just that — an idiom. The fact that the `!` operator has an effect on the return value almost always doesn't matter, because the return value is being completely ignored by the calling environment. Thus

```
+function() {
  // whatever
}();
```

is effectively exactly the same, even though the `+` unary operator is different from the `!` unary operator.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I mean. I understand from the question I linked that this syntax saves a byte, but why would you want to reverse the opposite value that is being returned? Doesn't `console.log(!!function() { return true; }());` make more sense?

Comment: I have reread a few more times. Are you saying that this syntax only makes sense when a function doesn't return anything?

Comment: From the answer I linked: _"Sometimes we want to call a function right as we create it. You might be tempted to try this:

`function () {}()`
but it results in a SyntaxError."_ Why does that result in a syntax error. I don't understand why it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @thomas: Because the engine interprets `function () {}` as a function *declaration* and declarations need a name. The `!` in front of the function makes the engine interpret it as a function *expression*, which don't need names. That's the only purpose of the `!` in this situation. You could use any other unary operator to achieve the same effect (such as `+`, `void` or `-`).

Comment: @FelixKling +1, getting there..bear with me. Just to be clear, the `!` has nothing to do with the return value—it only ensures that the function is immediately expressed, ie. invoked, yes?

Comment: @thomas it's **both** - by forcing the parser to interpret the function as a function instantiation expression instead of a function declaration statement, it allows the immediate invocation. However, a `!` is a `!`, so it **also** inverts the logical sense of the return value. When this idiom is used, the return value is *almost never* of any concern to the greater code context. The `+` or `-` or `~` unary operators are almost always just as good at this job.

Answer (score 2):

Functions that have either an empty return statement or a non-existent one return the value undefined upon their invocation. Applying ! to "falsy" values such as 0, null, undefined return true.