# What does this jQuery function mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to understand how a js library works, more specifically http://toopay.github.io/bootstrap-markdown/.

The whole js file is wrapped in this function:

```
!function ($) {
}(window.jQuery);
```

What does this do and how would I be able to call it again from outside the library?

Comment: This is immediately invoked function, similar to `(function($) {})(jQuery)`.

Comment: how can I reinvok this function from outside the library when I need it?

Comment: You can't and you should not. It's used only to create a function scope to protect the value of `$` and make sure that inside this function `$` is always points to `jQuery`.

Comment: Why do you think you need to reinvoke it?

Comment: my real problem is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905685/rails-stange-behaviour-when-using-bootstrap-markdown-gem @Juhana

Comment: I thought that if I can recall this initialisation function manually on my page I would be able to generate the element I need. @Juhana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a function then immediately calls it. The reason it does that is just so all the variables it makes won't be global, as they'll be inside the function instead. [The `!` is just to avoid causing problems when it's concatenated with other scripts and to save space.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

You can't call it yourself, nor should you.