# How and when does rails load a gem library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, javascript, rails-routing

I have a gem installed : http://toopay.github.io/bootstrap-markdown/

This library is supposedd to turn a textarea element into a stylized mardown editor.

To do this I used the following code:

```
 <div class="well col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
 <%= form_for(:post, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field(:title, class: 'form-control')%>
    <%= f.text_field(:description, class: 'form-control')%>
    <%= f.text_area(:content, rows: 15, "data-provide" => "markdown")%>
    <%= f.button "Submit", type: 'submit', class: 'btn col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 btn-large btn-success'%>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Initially I put this code on my root page and it worked perfectly.
I then created a new controller and moved it to a different view. I was accessing that view by manually typing the url in the browser: localhost:3000/controller/view and the page loaded perfectly.

Result here: [image]

However, when I access the page through a link on a different page, the form was not stylized.

Result: [image]

The odd thing is that if I reload the page it applies all the changes.

I made a temporary ugly hack that reloads the page one on every access:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    //Check if the current URL contains '#'
    if(document.URL.indexOf("#")==-1){
        // Set the URL to whatever it was plus "#".
        url = document.URL+"#";
        location = "#";

        //Reload the page
        location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

But there must be a decent explanation for what is going on.

I went through the library itself and added some console.log statements.
It seems that the library is loaded and initialisez on the home page but when I click the link it does not run anything anymore.

I am trying really hard to understand if this is a rails problem or a library one.

Comment: What happens when you hit F5? Is the site then displayed correctly? This is a bug in the rails development mode,...

Comment: YES if I hit F5 it displayes correctly! I have been spending more than 2 days on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with Turbolinks. First, remove data-provide attribute to initialize input yourself and add a class, like `markdown-editor`.

```
<%= f.text_area(:content, rows: 15, class: "markdown-editor")%>
```

Second, add a Javascript initializer:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function(){
  $(".markdown-editor").markdown()
});
```

Then it will be initialized on each page load.

Comment: IT WORKED! I have been trying to do this for ages for I did not know how to manually call the markdown initializer. I did not really understand what this function meant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907794/what-does-this-jquery-function-mean and couldnot decipher how the library worked

Comment: Thank you so mmuch I wish I could give you more in return than an up and accept answer! You are awesome! I spent more than 10 hours trying to figure this out!

Comment: I wish I knew what turbolinks were.. The turorials I've been ffollowing saud they are more advanced and that I shouldn't worry about them atm.

Comment: Yeah, it's the most often experienced problem when you're learning Rails :)