# Javascript Syntax: AngularJS Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax, filter, ternary-operator

I have found this excellent code for applying a filter in AngularJS [here](https://gist.github.com/builtbylane/7237798). It works as expected, although I'm a little unsure on what the shortening using ! ? and : in this context would replace.

From experience, it looks like the ? and : are a ternary operators, although I'm not entirely certain what function the ! has.

From looking around stackoverflow, it seems like the ! has multiple functions depending on context, i.e. [3755606](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function).

```js
 app.filter('myFilterName', function () {
    return function (value) {
        return (!value) ? '' : value.replace(/ /g, '');
    };
  });
```

Comment: The `!` operator only does one thing, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!` is the [*logical NOT operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9): It coerces its argument to a boolean value, then inverts that value (e.g., true becomes false and false becomes true). `if (!value)` checks to see if `value` has a falsey value. What's a "falsey" value? Any value that becomes false when coerced to a boolean. That's `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `NaN`, `0`, and of course, `false`.

The `test ? one_thing : another_thing` is the [*conditional operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12). If the value that is being tested is truthy, the expression after the `?` is evaluated and the conditional expression takes that result; if not, the expression after the `:` is evaluated and the conditional expression takes *that* result. *(You'll sometimes hear the conditional operator called the "ternary" operator. It's true that it's **a** ternary operator [an operator that accepts three operands], and it's the only ternary operator currently in JavaScript, but its proper name is the 'conditional operator'. In theory, someday other ternary operators could be added to the language...)*

So the net result of:

```
return (!value) ? '' : value.replace(/ /g, '');
```

is:

- Coerce `value` to boolean: Falsey values become `false`, all other values become `true`.
- Invert that boolean.
- If the inverted boolean is `true`, return `''`; otherwise, evaluate `value.replace(/ /g, '')` and return the result.

My guess is that `value` is always a string. If so, then the short version is: If `value` is `""`, return `""`; otherwise, return the contents of `value` with all spaces removed.

---

Side note: the `()` around `!value` are completely unnecessary.