# What does !(function()) mean in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript, parsley.js

I saw in the [ParsleyJs](http://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.js) library the folowing:

[image]

What does the expression `!(function(f){...})` mean?
Is it a negation?

EDIT:
After some explanations, I observed that actually the code looks like

```
!( f(y){}( f(x){} ) );
```

or can be written as

```
!( f(z) );
```

or

```
!(Z);
```

where `Z = f(z)`, `z = f(y){}`, and finally `y = f(x){}`...
So is not really clear what function executes the expression `!(Z);`

Comment: I suspect that it means the programmer was superstitious. It's completely unnecessary in the posted code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Comment: It's pointless as the IIFE is already wrapped in parenthesis.

Comment: Well - it look's like this actually `!(function(f){...} (function ($){...}));` It doesn't look like anything is actually ever called

Comment: actually there is `!( f(y){}( f(x){} ) );` or can be written as **`!( f(z) );`** where `z = f(y){}`, where `y = f(x){}`, so not really clear what for is the `!(Z);`

Comment: @Pointy I think you are wrong: actually there is `!(f(z));` that is an expression. Without will be `(f(z));` -  perhaps not the same thing....

Comment: No, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

It is a short-hand or alternative for self-invoking anonymous function.

```
(function(){
//code
})();`
```

can be written as

```
!function(){
// code
}();
```

you can also use + instead of !.

Comment: actually there is `!( f(y){}( f(x){} ) );` or can be written as **`!( f(z) );`** where `z = f(y){}`, where `y = f(x){}`, so not really clear what for is the `!(z);`

Answer (score 2):

Usually you use either

```
!function(f){...}()
```

or

```
(function(f){...})()
```

or

```
+function(f){...}()
```

The developers here combined the first two, which is redundant.

Comment: Beware of the last once since `+` is overloaded as a binary operator, so it has the same potential issues as `()` or any binary/postfix operator. Unary prefix operators are best for this. In the past, I've used `void` since it stands out.

Comment: Stolen from the links in the comments: Another benefit is that ! causes a semi-colon insertion, so it's impossible for this version to be wrongly concatenated with a file that doesn't end with a ;

Comment: ...and this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: actually there is `!( f(y){}( f(x){} ) );` or can be written as **`!( f(z) );`** where `z = f(y){}`, where `y = f(x){}`, so not really clear what for is the `!(z);`