# Target certain div / li with css attribute with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder if I can target a `div` with certain class or pseudo. 
I think the answer could be some "`if else`" but I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm working on some forms that are showed by steps that the users navigates with <kbd>continue</kbd> and <kbd>back</kbd> buttons.

The "steps" are separated by `ol li`. 
After that, I have 3 "buttons": <kbd>back</kbd>, <kbd>continue</kbd> and <kbd>send</kbd>.

```
<section class="modal-questions">
        <form id="form001" name="form001" method="post">
            <div class="modal-questions-list">
                <ol>
                    <!-- question 01 -->
                    <li class="li-visible">
                        <h4>Question 01</h4>
                        <input id="opt1a" type="radio" name="Q1" value="1">
                        <label for="opt1a">Options</label>
                    </li>

                    <!-- question 02 -->
                    <li>
                        <h4>Question 02</h4>
                        <input id="opt2b" type="radio" name="Q2" value="1">
                        <label for="opt2b">Options</label>
                    </li>

                    <!-- question 03 -->
                    <li>
                        <h4>Question 0</h4>
                        <input id="opt3b" type="radio" name="Q3" value="1">
                        <label for="opt3b">Options</label>
                    </li>

                    <!-- question 04 -->
                    <li>
                        <h4>Question 04</h4>
                        <input id="opt4b" type="radio" name="Q4" value="1">
                        <label for="opt4b">Options</label>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>

    <section class="modal-bottom">
        <div class="X-button-flat" id="prevStep">
            Back
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="X-button-small s-button-orange" id="nextStep">
            Continue
        </div>

        <div class="X-button-small s-button-orange" id="finalStep">
            Send
        </div>
    </section>
```

In CSS, `li` are hidden except the one that has `.li-visible` - the one that user is seeing.

```
 li {
   display: none;
 }

 .li-visible {
   display: block;
 }
```

With JQuery, when the user clicks <kbd>continue</kbd> I `removeClass('li-visible')` to the `li` that has it, and add it to the `next` one to show it to the user.  And when the user clicks <kbd>back</kbd> I do the same but to the previous `li`.

```
$('.modal-bottom').on('click', '#nextStep', function() {
    $('li.li-visible').removeClass('li-visible').next().addClass('li-visible');
    $('#prevStep').css({'opacity':'1'});
});

$('.modal-bottom').on('click', '#prevStep', function() {
    $('li.li-visible').removeClass('li-visible').prev().addClass('li-visible');
});
```

So far so good. Now the problems:

1. When the user reaches the last but one question when clicks <kbd>continue</kbd>, i want to hide that button and show <kbd>send</kbd> button.
2. When the users clicks <kbd>back</kbd> in the second question, I want to hide that button.

P.S.
In this example there are 4 Questions, but the form doesn't has a fixed number of questions, so it has to work in 3 or 99 questions.

There is the [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sandrin4p/1op240xo/2/)

Comment: You might like to consider proper buttons instead of divs - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ufjkqf4/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`:first-child`**](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and [**`:last-child`**](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selectors

```
$('#prevStep, #finalStep').hide();

$('.modal-bottom').on('click', '#nextStep', function() {
    var i = $('li.li-visible').removeClass('li-visible').next().addClass('li-visible');
    if(i.is(':last-child')){
        $(this).hide();
        $('#finalStep').show();
    }
    $('#prevStep').show();
});

$('.modal-bottom').on('click', '#prevStep', function() {
    var i = $('li.li-visible').removeClass('li-visible').prev().addClass('li-visible');
    if(!i.is(':last-child')){
        $('#nextStep').show();
        $('#finalStep').hide();
    }
    if(i.is(':first-child')){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

(Note: I have used [**`.hide()`**](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [**`.show()`**](https://api.jquery.com/show/) methods instead of `.css(...)`)

[**JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rh1sbv1o/)

---

Or a bit more compact solution, with [**`.toggle(display)`**](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display):

```
$('.modal-bottom').on('click', '#nextStep', function() {
    var i = $('.li-visible').removeClass('li-visible').next().addClass('li-visible').is(':last-child');
    $(this).toggle(!i);
    $('#finalStep').toggle(i);
    $('#prevStep').show();
});

$('.modal-bottom').on('click', '#prevStep', function() {
    var i = $('.li-visible').removeClass('li-visible').prev().addClass('li-visible').is(':last-child');
    $('#nextStep').toggle(!i);
    $('#finalStep').toggle(i);
    $(this).toggle(!$('li.li-visible').is(':first-child'));
});
```

[**JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ebsfyn3u/)

Comment: Thank you so much! What is the meaning of "!" ? Is it like "!important" in css?

Comment: @SandrinaPereira, no, `!` here is used for something else (to determine whether the condition is `falsy`). http://stackoverflow.com/a/3755630/962734