# Javascript !function

Tags: javascript

I use jQuery-UI for an application. This Application uses drag and drop and for mobile support i use jQuery UI Touch Punch.

I was wondering why the function look like this:

```
!function (a) {
  //code stuff
}(jQuery);
```

I've never seen an exclamation mark in front of a function.

Here you see the full code:
https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/blob/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

What is this good for?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Comment: Isn't that a song... "Hey Bang, what are you good for"?

Comment: *...absolutely nothing* ;)