# what dose this code mean?(window), function (a, b, c)

Tags: javascript

what does this code mean?
I saw the code on some website. I don't know how it works.
I have simplified the code.

`(window), function (a, b, c){}`

Comment: Not much without the surrounding context.

Comment: You over-simplified. Please un-simplify and show us some context.

Comment: http://s1.mi.com/m/e/2063c1608d6e0baf80249c42e2be5.js you can saw the code in this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function), there are a something like:

```
!function(a){console.log(a+" First")}(window),
function(a){console.log(a+" Second")}(window),
function(a,b,c){console.log(a+' '+b+' '+c)}("MI_STD_CRYPTED","MI_GOODS_ID",window);
```

Execute the block above in the console of your browser.
In your script:

```
!function(a){..}(window),
function(a){..}(window),
function(a,b,c){..}("MI_STD_CRYPTED","MI_GOODS_ID",window);
```

i.e. we run an anonymous function with parameters in the round brackets, an anonymous function accepts these parameters as arguments:

```
!function(){}(),
function(a,b,c){console.log(a+' '+b+' '+c)}("this will be a","this will be b","this will be c");
```

Comment: I haven't see the code like mine in the post.