# How to override 3rd part js function

Tags: javascript

I have this code for :

```
  (function(d,t,p){
    var e = d.createElement(t); e.charset = "utf-8"; e.src = p;
    var s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(e,s)
   })(document,"script","http://js.testfreaks.com/onpage/gymsource.com/prd.js")
```

As you can see [here](http://js.testfreaks.com/onpage/gymsource.com/prd.js) this script is being included in my website.in this script a function used.

```
   function a(e, r) {

    }
```

I want to override it.
Is it is possiable ?

Comment: Why not copy it down to a .js file and then edit/remove the function?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to override the `function a(e, r){}`.

As you can see in `http://js.testfreaks.com/onpage/gymsource.com/prd.js`. The main code is wrapped with below code, which means the `function a(e, r){}` is not in global scope, but inside the scope of below function.

```
!function(t,e){
  // all the code
}(jQuery,testFreaks);
```

Only when the function is in global scope,  will you be able to override it

Refer to:
[What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)