# Meaning of !function in Javascript self invoking function

Tags: javascript

Reading some third party code, a self invoking function starts with !function. What is the meaning of the exclamation mark in this context?

```
!function(){ // not assigned to variable or returned
  //code here

}()
```

Comment: Oops, I mean this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function

Comment: It does a logic NOT (the `!`) on the result of the self invoking function.

Comment: it forces the following expression to evaluate. (but only for this case, `void` is the statement of choice.)

Comment: it's one character shorter than wrapping the whole function expression in parentheses before calling it.

Comment: and it also prevents the line being misinterpreted as a continuation of the previous one if there wasn't a semicolon. Lines starting with a parens can be risky so if you count the semicolon, this is TWO whole characters shorter! :D

Comment: Putting this character there makes it a function expression.