# The usage of function (function(parameter) {

Tags: javascript, function

I have a couple questions about the below code:

- What kind of function is this that has brackets on left side but no
  name before function ? Is this a special kind of function ?
- Basically this function accepts callback as listeners, is it defined
  and run together ?

_

```
 (function(handlers) {
  Object.keys(handlers).forEach(function(observableName) {
    var observable = app.ko.observable().extend({
      notify: 'always'
    });
    that[observableName] = observable;
    var f = handlers[observableName];
    if (f) {
      observable.subscribe(f);
    }
  });
})({
  onCallIgnored: defaultCallHandler,
  onCallStateChanged: function(call) {
    that.videoState(call.getRemoteVideoState());
  },
  onPlacingCall: function(call) {
    callParams = app.utils.cloneObj(call);
  },
  onIncomingCall: function(call) {
    that.activeCall = call;
    callParams = app.utils.cloneObj(call);
    setCallEstablishingTimeout();
    app.playSound("ringtone");
    that.callProgressTime("");
  },
  onUpdateCallInfo: function(call) {
    console.log(call);
  }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

```
(function(handlers) {
  ...
})()
```

is a self-executing anonymous function(also known as Immediately Invoked Function Expression). See [this tutorial](http://esbueno.noahstokes.com/post/77292606977/self-executing-anonymous-functions-or-how-to-write)
for good explanation.

When this code is executed by the JS interpreter it will define and call the function immediately with the set of handlers you are passing as parameters.

Comment: Try "Immediately Invoked Function Expression"

Comment: Same idea different wording, no?

Comment: It should be `(function (handlers) {
  ...
})()`

Comment: Without the `()` behind it, it will not be invoked

Comment: Tanks. wikipedia says that until recently JavaScript had only function scope but not block scope, so this kind of usage is not needed with latest javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of function is this that has brackets on left side but no
>   name before function ? Is this a special kind of function ?

The function is an `anonymous` function which is converted as a `function expression` by wrapping `()` around it. And by adding another `()`, you are invoking the function expression. Such invoked function expressions are knows as [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) which means you invoke the function as soon as it is defined.

e.g.

```js
(function(x) {console.log(x);})(2); // paints 2
```

> Basically this function accepts callback as listeners, is it defined
>   and run together ?

Yes, the function is defined and run together. IIFE takes the values defined in `()` as arguments and pass it to the function.

```
(function(arg1, arg2, ...argN){ ... // function definition})(param1, param2, ... paramN);
```

So, the breakup of the IIFE will be as follows

**function defintion**

```
function(handlers) {
  Object.keys(handlers).forEach(function(observableName) {
    var observable = app.ko.observable().extend({
      notify: 'always'
    });
    that[observableName] = observable;
    var f = handlers[observableName];
    if (f) {
      observable.subscribe(f);
    }
  });
}
```

**function argument 1 (handlers)**

```
{
  onCallIgnored: defaultCallHandler,
  onCallStateChanged: function(call) {
    that.videoState(call.getRemoteVideoState());
  },
  onPlacingCall: function(call) {
    callParams = app.utils.cloneObj(call);
  },
  onIncomingCall: function(call) {
    that.activeCall = call;
    callParams = app.utils.cloneObj(call);
    setCallEstablishingTimeout();
    app.playSound("ringtone");
    that.callProgressTime("");
  },
  onUpdateCallInfo: function(call) {
    console.log(call);
  }
}
```