# Javascript: syntax and the new keyword

Tags: javascript, syntax

Consider a class defined as:

```
class Foo { static bar() { return this; } }
```

I can construct an instance with `new (Foo.bar())()`.

But `new Foo.bar()()` results in an `Uncaught TypeError: Foo.bar is not a constructor`.

Why are those extra parentheses necessary?

Comment: `new Foo.bar()()` is identical to `(new Foo.bar())()`.

Comment: Because `bar` is not a constructor.

Comment: Order of operations.  First example, call foo.bar(), whatever it returns make a `new` instance of that, then execute it.  Second example, make a `new` foo.bar, execute it and assuming it returns a function execute that as well.  Quite different.

Comment: @ASDFGerte why?

Comment: (My assumption is this comes down to some operator precedence thing -- aka new with arguments is higher than function call but lower than grouping?)

Comment: It's somewhat an edge-case, as function calls and new are in the same group when it comes to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), and new is somewhat odd in the spec, but it's how the parsing works, you can check e.g. with https://astexplorer.net/

Comment: @ASDFGerte Sorta what I figured. Thanks. And thanks for the link to astexplorer.net -- hadn't seen that before.

Comment: Generally, when writing code, and precedence is not immediately clear (uncommon, tricky situation), add explicit braces. Even if you don't need braces, but it's one of these edge cases, then people who are not completely submerged in the material may read the code, and get confused. Of course, it is always beneficial to know the precedence, but often, adding a pair of braces too many helps readability. Another note: the error finally stems from class methods not being constructors. They don't have [[Construct]], and cannot be used with `new`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Given i can't find a suitable duplicate, could you please post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Foo.bar()()` is identical to `(new Foo.bar())()`.

Looking at the [MDN page for operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), `new` and a function call are in the same group. In the spec, the handling of `new` can be somewhat confusing. However, `new` will be done first.

A nice tool to check, how a specific snippet is being parsed, is https://astexplorer.net/ - it allows you to look at the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) which is the result of parsing.

The error message you get then comes from `Foo.bar` being a class method, which don't have [[Construct]], and cannot be used with `new`.

As a tip: when it is slightly unclear, how an expression will be parsed, then adding explicit braces often improves readability, even when they may not be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

- First, you need to know what is IIFE(immediately invoked function expression).
  IIFE is as name suggested you can call a function immediately after declared. But JS parser should see whole as one expression.

Ex.

`(function(){console.log("foo")}())`

`!function(){console.log("foo")}()`

`+function(){console.log("foo")}()`

All these forces parser to see `function(){console.log("foo")}()` side of it as complete expression so it can call immediately.

- Second, how `new (Foo.bar())()` works.

When you use `new (Foo.bar())()` in first parentheses returns `this` which is `Foo` itself. Because `bar` method is returning `Foo`. After second parentheses`()` calls it(Foo) and then `new` is creates a new instance of `Foo`. Basically you are writing `new Foo()` with using IIEF.

- Third why `new Foo.bar()()` throws error.

When JS parser sees the expression `new Foo.bar()` it is immediately try creates an instance if `Foo.bar` and `Foo.bar`is not a constructor. After that JS throws that error.

But if parser sees `()` it could throw another error that `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'`. Because JS can not understand the what is left from that line, `()`.

Difference between

`new Foo.bar()()` and `new (Foo.bar())()`

same as

`function(){console.log("foo")}()` and `(function(){console.log("foo")})()`

it throws different error and stop parsing, because `Foo.bar` is not a constructor to call.

I hope it helps.

Some links to understand.
[What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Comment: No, this has absolutely nothing to do with IIFEs.