# $injector:modulerr - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I am learning Angular JS from codeschool course "Shaping up with angular js". The guy on the videos says, that wrapping code in (`function(){}`) is a good habbit.

BUT, when I do that I`m getting an error`[$injector:modulerr]`. Without this self-called function syntax everything works fine. And it bothers me, why they tell to do this way, and why does it cause error?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Think this post will help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421911/what-is-the-purpose-of-wrapping-whole-javascript-files-in-anonymous-functions-li

Comment: @RahulB, sure. `code
(function() {


    var app = angular.module("gemStore", []);

    var gems = [{
        name: "Dodecahedron",
        price: 2,
        desc: "some description",
        canPurchase: true
    }, {
        name: "Pentagonal gem",
        price: 5.95,
        desc: "...",
        canPurchase: true
    }
    ];

    app.controller("StoreController", function () {
        this.products = gems;
    });

})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you are missing the `();` self executing braces at the end of your anonymous function:

```
(function(){
  // all your code
})();
//^^^--------------add this (); at the closing.
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the format should look like this:

```
angular.module("gemStore", []).controller("StoreController", function () {
    var gems = [
        { name: "Dodecahedron", price: 2, desc: "some description", canPurchase: true },
        { name: "Pentagonal gem", price: 5.95, desc: "...", canPurchase: true }
    ];
    this.products = gems;
})
```

Comment: `angular.module("gemStore", [])controller` you missed a `.` dot before `controller`.