# node JavaScript files and global namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js

When writing JavaScript for webpages it is good practice to wrap files in an anonymous self-executing function to avoid polluting the global namespace. See [What is the purpose of wrapping whole Javascript files in anonymous functions like “(function(){ … })()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421911/what-is-the-purpose-of-wrapping-whole-javascript-files-in-anonymous-functions-li)

When writing JavaScript files in a server-side NodeJS environment is it still useful to wrap my files in this anonymous function?

Comment: One of the benefits of node modules is that nothing is global by default as a module is already in it's own private namespace.  So only things you explicitly attach to the `global` object will be global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to do that in Node, your code is already wrapped in a function by default:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  // YOUR CODE INJECTED HERE!
});
```

For more information, read http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/.