# In JavaScript, what is the benefit of wrapping a pseudo class in an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife

Here is an example of a pseudo class in an IIFE

```
// cow.js
(function(exports) {
  "use strict";

  function Cow(name) {
    this.name = name || "Anon cow";
  }
  exports.Cow = Cow;

  Cow.prototype = {
    greets: function(target) {
      if (!target)
        throw new Error("missing target");
      return this.name + " greets " + target;
    }
  };
})(this);
```

What is the benefit of that over the following:

```
  "use strict";

  function Cow(name) {
    this.name = name || "Anon cow";
  }
  exports.Cow = Cow;

  Cow.prototype = {
    greets: function(target) {
      if (!target)
        throw new Error("missing target");
      return this.name + " greets " + target;
    }
  };
```

Don't both of these end up adding the Cow 'constructor' function to the global scope?

The cow.js file is being included via the HTML document in a script tag. That means that the value of `this` is window. Isn't that the same global scope that both examples will use to add the function to?

Could someone provide an example of using this in a module or different scope?

This is not a duplicate, as the IFFE in the following related question does not take a parameter - [What is the purpose of wrapping whole Javascript files in anonymous functions like “(function(){ … })()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421911/what-is-the-purpose-of-wrapping-whole-javascript-files-in-anonymous-functions-li)

The code was copied from here: https://nicolas.perriault.net/code/2013/testing-frontend-javascript-code-using-mocha-chai-and-sinon/

Comment: @Tushar could you please explain this in more detail?

Comment: In the second example Cow becomes a global method (supposed it is defines at window scope, so it becomes window.Cow), while it's not in the first example.

Comment: I don't think this a duplicate. It is asking about the use of 'this' which the other question does not address  explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the scope - in the 1st case everything is defined in an anonymous function scope, in 2nd case in global scope. The benefit of IIFE is module encapsulation, you can define a function/class with the same name in each module without affecting another one.

Comment: I have added more detail to the question, about the fact  that this script is being included via an HTML page. Doesn't this mean that both version are adding `Cow` the the window scope?