# Accessing variable outside a function's scope but not making it global (window.hazaa)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, scope, window

I have a list of elements, performing a function on each. Said function results in a subtotal which I wish to add to a grand total. Since I prefer to keep the *window* as unabused as possible, I declared the variable in my script right before the list declaration.

```
var total = 0;
$.each($("input[flag]:checked"), function(index, value){
  var sub =+ value.attributes["blipp"].value;
  total += sub; // this is window.total not my total!
});
```

I do remember that the scoping in JavaScript is less than well design, so I expected something unwanted to happen. And so I was right. The question is if it's possible to enclose the variable somehow and still keep it accessible form the individual function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scope with a [IIFE, Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2421911/2256325), just for that reason and do:

```
(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $.each($("input[flag]:checked"), function(index, value){
      total += value.attributes["blipp"].value;
    });
    // do something with total here...
})();
```

This way there will be a variable created in a scope that self-consumes itself.

---

**You can also use native JavaScript** and a normal function to create a new scope (altough I dont need a new variable):

```
function getTotal(sel) {
    var els = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
    return els.reduce(function(total, input) {
        var val = input.checked ? parseInt(input.value, 10) : 0;
        return total + val;
    }, 0);
}
console.log(getTotal('input[flag]')); // 45
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2s64cjrp/

Comment: Will the function be invoked without an explicit call?

Comment: @KonradViltersten yes. It gets invoked "automagically" since we add `()` in the end of `(function(){})`

Comment: Also, I've always wondered - shouldn't it be the same as skipping the function keyword and putting my stuff doing this: *({my-stuff-here})();*? What kind of functionality is **not** being invoked if we skip the function thingy?

Comment: @KonradViltersten inside that IIFE the scope is new and will not go out. You can do some stuff like `(alert(10))()` without the keyword `function`, but I would not do it. Also if you need multiline and `;` it will break

Comment: Forget it. I just saw that it's a link under *IIFE*. Once I read that answer, everything is Amazing Grace now ("*...I was blind and now I see...*"). +1 for that.

Comment: @KonradViltersten nice. I added a new example also, in case its usefull. Such IIFE are really nice for not poluting global scope.

Answer (score 2):

So many ways to do this, but a common one would be to wrap all of it in another function:

```
function total(){
    var total = 0;
    $.each($("input[flag]:checked"), function(index, value){
    var sub =+ value.attributes["blipp"].value;
    total += sub; 
    });        
    return total;  
}
```