# What is the purpose/benefit of anonymous functions (or whatever this is) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

I've seen a lot of apps for the past few weeks that have this kind of script at the beginning of the script:

```
(function() {
  // Code goes here...
});
```

Can anyone explain this or have a link to some resources about this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anonymous functions are functions that are dynamically declared at
>   runtime. They’re called anonymous functions because they aren’t given
>   a name in the same way as normal functions.
>
> Anonymous functions are declared using the function operator instead
>   of the function declaration. You can use the function operator to
>   create a new function wherever it’s valid to put an expression. For
>   example you could declare a new function as a parameter to a function
>   call or to assign a property of another object.

[Here](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/) is the article.

Comment: Nice...I liked the article too. But why is it used in the beginning of js file, wrapped around the whole script?

Comment: That makes your script be separated well from the global space. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421911/what-is-the-purpose-of-wrapping-whole-javascript-files-in-anonymous-functions-li

Comment: My answer actually explained this >_>... just saying...

Comment: Time to find a new reference. *Anonymous functions are functions that are dynamically declared at runtime.* **All** functions are dynamically declared at runtime.  *They aren’t given a name in the same way as normal functions.* They are just as "normal" as functions without names. *Anonymous functions are declared using the function operator...* There is no such thing as a "function operator".

Answer (score 1):

`"use strict"` is used to make sure all variables are declared. For instance, I can do without an error:

```
x = 3;
```

although it is not declared, but I cannot do:

```
"use strict";
x = 3;
```

without throwing an error. I must use:

```
"use strict";
var x = 3;
```

---

`"use strict"` can be used for `function`s. For example:

```
x = 3; // no error
myFunc();
function myFunc() {
    "use strict";
    y = 3; // error
}
```

### Edit

You also cannot `delete` a variable when in `use strict` mode.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this would likely be like:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict"
  var x = 1;
  document.write("I am inside the function scope and x=", x, "<br/>");
}())

if (typeof(x) === "undefined") {
  document.write("I am outside the function scope and x=undefined");
}
```

The function creates a scope that you can use to prevent setting variables and such on the global scope.  "use strict" helps with keeping code clean and throws errors with common mistakes that can cause bugs (like redeclaring variables of the same name.  Notice in the code above, var x is set inside the function scope.  Outside the function scope it is undefined.  If you loaded these 2 things in different .js files and were from different authors they could each use their own "var x" and they would not conflict because they are in different scopes instead of set on the global scope.

As far as "use strict" mode and what specifically it prevents you can see more details for that in the documentation here:
[MDN "use strict" docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

For reference, the function at the start of this code is considered an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).