# Why declaration of variable in closure environment did not work?

Tags: javascript, closures

As my understanding, closure makes an environment to link functions and parameters outside the function and allow things inside the function to access them.

As below is a function with closure. When I execute this function three times.

```
add();
add();
add();
```

I expect I should get 1, because everytime I execute add(), It will redeclare counter as 0 and add 1. So it should be *counter = 0, counter++, counter = 0, counter++, counter = 0, counter++.* But why it turned out to be **3**?

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
```

Second question is :

```
variable = (function() {})()
```

Why we add an extra parenthesis to enclose the function, and why another extra parenthesis after the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expect I should get 1, because everytime I execute add(), It will redeclare counter as 0 and add 1.

No, exactly not. `add` refers to the function you are *returning* from the IIFE, i.e. to `function () {return counter += 1;}`. This function doesn't set `counter` to 0.

Lets just log `add` and have a look at it:

[image]

Do you see now that calling `add` will simply add `1` to `counter`, and nothing else?

Maybe the code is easier to understand if you extract the function. The following code has exactly the same result as yours:

```
function createAdd() {
  var counter = 0;
  return function () {return counter += 1;}
}

// we are *calling* createAdd here, so `add` refers
// to the function defined in line 3 ( function () {return counter += 1;} )
var add = createAdd();

add();
add();
add();
```

Here you can see that `createAdd` (and therefore the line `var counter = 0`) is executed only once, but the function *returned* from `createAdd` is executed multiple times.

> Why we add an extra parenthesis to enclose the function, and why another extra parenthesis after the function?

This is called a *immediately invoked function expression* (IIFE). It defines a function and immediately executes it. This is often done to limit the scope of variables (in this case `counter`).

You can think of `(function() {}())` being equivalent to

```
function f() {}
(f())
```

The IIFE just puts the declaration and execution of the function into a single expression. This allows us to omit the function name so that we don't pollute the scope.

Related question:

- [What do parentheses surrounding a object/function/class declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/440739/218196)
- [What is the purpose of wrapping whole Javascript files in anonymous functions like “(function(){ … })()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2421911/218196)

---

> Why declaration of variable in closure environment did not work?

I'd say it works correctly as intended.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, shouldn't the function execute line by line? Everytime when add was invoked, It should execute var `counter = 0`, then execute `return` right?

Comment: *"shouldn't the function execute line by line"* yes of course. *"Everytime when add was invoked, It should execute ..."* No. It does not, as I explained in the answer: *"add refers to the function you are **returning** from the IIFE, i.e. to `function () {return counter += 1;}`. "* I added some more information. You could also just do a `console.log(add)` and see what the value of `add` is.

Comment: Thanks for you detail explanation! I am gonna try it ~