# Purpose to create anonymous function and call it immediately

Tags: javascript

I was following an angularjs tutorial, and I encountered something like this:

```
(function(){
    'use strict'
    angular.module('users',['ngMaterial]);
})();
```

I was wondering what is the difference between that and this:

```
angular.module('users',['ngMaterial']);
```

As far as my understanding goes, both define a new angularjs module, but I am guessing there is more to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421911/what-is-the-purpose-of-wrapping-whole-javascript-files-in-anonymous-functions-li + if it's a tutorial they're probably adding more stuff later.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var module1=angular.module('users',['ngMaterial']);
console.log(window.module1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

With the above snippet. It is a global variable and will be copied into global object(window)

```js
(function(){
    'use strict'
    var  module1=angular.module('users',['ngMaterial']);
  console.log(module1);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

with this snippet, your making it to not copy into window(global) object and modularising the code

Hope it helps