# What's the best way to manage Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a new web application, I haven't got problem with backend part (it's my job until 6years) but i'm little new with frontend development (around 1 year). What's the best way to manage your JS code?

At this time I use a single file (app.js) where i call many function like this:

```
writer.init();
other.init();
```

writer and other are functions like this

```
function () {

var writer = {
  "init": function() {
    // do something
  }
}

}()
```

I think it's an ugly way. What are the best practices?

Comment: Why exactly is that "ugly"?

Comment: Object Oriented JS. Take a look at angular.js or backbone.js

Comment: Coffeescript takes care of the "ugliness". And any kind of build system can concatenate multiple source files into a single file (and minify it, too).

Comment: knockout.js is your friend. Try googling it.

Comment: @Juhana because you want to split functionality up for easier navigation and better performance. In the example given with just two objects its not a big deal, but if you have 500 objects with multiple functions it would take pages longer to render the js code and be harder to maintain.

Comment: Start by reading all answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247209/current-commonly-accepted-best-practices-around-code-organization-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @all I use php to include <script src=""></script> at the good time (i think it's a best pratice but this way (use php) is worst. Sometimes i got just two lines of jquery to apply an effet, where i put this line ? In an other file ? I got an example of my practices in JS (http://www.benderphp.com) if you got a pretty solution, i'm ready to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a JavaScript framework that enforces some structure, like using directives with AngularjS. If you want to do it all yourself, [this chapter of *Eloquent JavaScript*](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter9.html) is a good read.

Comment: Eloquent is a good resource, thank's !

Answer (score 0):

The Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) provides a very nice way of organizing code in modules. It is especially aimed for client-side Javascript code. There are various implementations but I would recommend having a look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org).