# How to make grunt build minimize private (__) and protected (_) methods?

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs

I know that is not standard but is possible to configure it's scope? Maybe only private ones?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out this detailed article and discussion: [How Do You Structure JavaScript? The Module Pattern Edition](http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/). As pointed out in the article comments, this is not actually the module pattern.

Here are some other resources on the module pattern

- [JavaScript module pattern with example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19801321/1085891)
- [The Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)
- [JavaScript Module Pattern: In-Depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

As to your specific question, it doesn't appear possible based on some discussion I came across on gruntjs's GitHub.

> The original jshint task would still be callable without the build
>   task run before it. I see only two ways to make this work:
>
> 1. introduce a method of modifying tasks to add dependencies that need to
>      run before them
> 2. **I've seen discussions about making tasks private**. If
>      this change is introduced, your way of defining a new task which runs
>      the dependencies and the the actual (private) task would work too.

via https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/978#issuecomment-29388092

Comment: I agree and many folks discuss that problem in the comments of that article. For example, [this comment explains the problem and using modules instead](http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/#comment-256070).

Comment: I personally use: var Car = function(){}; _.(Car.prototype, {__run: function(){}}); For me this is the best. Anyway I would need to grunt to understand that __run's scope is only of this class