# Calling function from external .js file, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html

I have a really basic JavaScript project, I'm just testing out and learning the language. All I want the program to do is launch and call a function inside the external main.js file. At the moment nothing happens on launch.

I have tried copying examples given online but they don't seem to be working for me.

HTML File:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Cex_Program</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>Content goes here!</div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        Main();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file:

Content of function is irrelevant, I just want the program flow to enter the function (hit my breakpoint);

```js
// Your code here!

var InfiniteLoop = 1;
var DeltaTime = 0;

function Main()
{
    var Day = new Date();
    var StartTime = Math.round(new Date() / 1000);
    var StartCurrentLoopTime = 0;
    var EndCurrentLoopTime = 0;
}
```

Comment: you need eventListener on window load :)

Comment: @DylanSteele what do you mean? `Main()` is telling it to run. It's just that there's no output, or anything to show that the function has run.

Comment: You need special file structure: [![project root][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoreL.png

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Ok enter doesnt paragraph but sets the comment... Anyway i have the breakpoint set before i run the program (im in visual studio) and it never gets hit. I also added the consol.log(day) line as a check and it still doesnt work. (I see no output).

Answer (score 3):

## This does work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>Content goes here!</div>
    <script>function Main( str ) { console.log( str ); }</script>
    <script>
        Main( "Main!" );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### So

We can deduce from this that either `js/main.js` is not being downloaded, the function `Main()` is inaccessible to a `<script>` outside it or that `Main()` simply doesn't function or produce a discernable result.

See [this w3schools tutorial about scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) for more details on why `Main()` might be inaccessible.

Check your browser's console for errors in the case of `Main()` not functioning.

- FireFox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Browser_Console
- Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

I will happily update this answer as needed in response to *positive* feedback.

### To test if `Main()` is accessible

Check if `Main()` is a global function by finding out if [`window.hasOwnProperty( "Main" )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) before typing to use it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>Content goes here!</div>
    <script>
        ( function() {
            function Main( str ) { console.log( str ); }
        } () );
        function Alt( str ) { console.log( str ); }
    </script>
    <script>
        if ( window.hasOwnProperty( "Main" ) ) {
            Main( "Main!" );
        } else {
            console.error( "Main() can't be accessed from here" );
            if ( window.hasOwnProperty( "Alt" ) ) {
                Alt( "Alt!" );
            }
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm thinking that `Main` does run. It's just that nothing is being output, nor logged, etc.

Comment: I like being excellent!  --- _"produce a discernable result"_ - I'm betting on this.

Comment: Ok enter doesnt paragraph but sets the comment... Anyway i have the breakpoint set before i run the program (im in visual studio) and it never gets hit. I also added the consol.log(day) line as a check and it still doesnt work. (I see no output). repeat of comment i made above

Comment: @HDennis - Assuming `js/main.js` is being downloaded correctly (the path is good and the script loads without error), that `js/main.js` is being loaded synchronously, and that `Main()` is accessible (is [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514382/global-functions-in-javascript)) and functioning correctly; everything **should** be working as my example shows. To simplify your debugging, try removing the breakpoint, commenting out the content of `Main()` and replacing it with only a simple `console.log()`. If that doesn't happen, one or more of the other stated possibilities is likely.

Comment: "CSP14312: Resource violated directive ‘script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval'’ in Host Defined Policy: inline script. Resource will be blocked." Is being reported as a warning in the JavaScript Console, does that look related to you? I did try just console.log() but didnt see anything come up as a result of it. why would main.js not be being loaded synchronously? this is just a default new project in visual studio so the include paths and loading should all be defaulted and working i assume?

Comment: Trying out your code all i get in the console window is "Content goes here!", nothing shows up beneath it at all. I wonder if its not a code thing but a strange windows 10 or visual studio thing?

Comment: @HDennis - Ah, well, yes... If `js/main.js` is being blocked, you'll definitely have a problem. Whilst developing, it is a good idea to [set your `Content-Security_Policy` to `-Report-Only`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only). Do that and see if your call of `Main()` works as expected (the policy won't be enforced). Figuring out the conflict will be beyond the scope of this question, and if you need help with it, you should post another with the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I created your setup on my dev machine and loaded the html page.  Assuming the files are named correctly on your machine, I can confirm that the code did execute.

A good way to check if JavaScript is running correctly in the browser is to use a debugger:

- [Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)
- [Mozilla Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger)
- [Microsoft Edge/IE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/f12-devtools-guide/debugger)
- [Apple Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Debugger/Debugger.html)