# jQuery $.getScript - Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Tags: jquery

```
$.getScript("/js/my.js")
    .done(function(script, textStatus) {
        console.log(script);
        myFunction();
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        $("div.log").text("Triggered ajaxError handler.");
    });
```

The script argument in `.done` returns my entire js file which also includes `myFunction()`. However I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`

`my.js`

```
$(function () {
     function myFunction() {
        console.log("Worked!")
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the `myFuntction()` defined in your js file declared globally? or atleast available via a namespace `windows.myScript.myFunction()`

Comment: is `myFunction()` written correctly? Might there be any errors in the external js file? Without a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this is impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: you need to post the code of how `myFunction` is defined within `my.js`

Comment: Just edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and the only error I have is the fact that do not know anything about parameter you are passing

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: argument is not defined
```

If I remove the parameter and call your function like:

```
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
        console.log(script);
        myFunction();
    }
```

Is working fine.

Make sure the name of the function inside the JS file is exactly myFunction.
Maybe re-create it to avoid special characters.

Fully working example for me:

From JSP:

```
$.getScript("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/my.js")
    .done(function(script, textStatus) {
        console.log(script);
        myFunction();
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        $("div.log").text("Triggered ajaxError handler.");
    });
```

webapp\resources\js\my.js

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log("Worked!")
}
```

Comment: Ok. I'll check what the issue is. Function name is exactly the same.

Comment: With the update you did to the question I see that the way you have defined the function is "not ok"...I am going to update my answer how the function should be in order to call it simply by name as you are calling

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using the following. Reference -> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514382/global-functions-in-javascript) Basically got the idea from you guys regarding the global variable thing.

Inside `my.js`

```
MyObject = {
        abc: function () {
            console.log("Worked")
        }
    }
```

And I called it this way  `MyObject.abc()` inside `.done`