# JS function available in all files under same folder

Tags: javascript, function

I wrting API test in Mocha JS, have two files: 00_auth.js and utils.js
I want to create function in utils which is available in other files from same folder

utils.js

```html
utils = {
   randomStringGenerator: function (){
    return Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 7);
  }
};
```

and test js

```html
const chai = require('chai');
const mocha = require('mocha');
const config = require('../config');
const request = require('supertest')(url);
const assert = chai.assert;
const utils= require('./utils')



randomFirstName=utils.randomStringGenerator();
//randomLastName=stringGenerator();
randomMail=randomFirstName+'@'+randomLastName+'.pl';
auth_token = ''



describe('0_auth', () => {
    it('should return token for unauthorized user', function(done) {
    request
      .post('/rest/v1/auth/get-token')
      .set(config.headers) 
      .send({
          "deviceUuidSource": "DEVICE",
          "source" : "KIOSK",
          "deviceUuid" : "uniquedeviceuuid"
      })
      .end(function(err,res){
        assert.equal(res.status,200)
        assert.property(res.body, 'token')
        assert.isString(res.body.token)
        auth_token=res.body.token
        console.log('unathorized token: '+auth_token) 
        done(err);
      });       
   });
});
```

I took this solution from [Global functions in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514382/global-functions-in-javascript), but it's not working, gives me Type Error :utils.randomStringGenerator is not a function

Comment: You need to export it using `module.exports`

Comment: Since you use `require`, you still need to export from the module properly

Comment: "*available in other files from same folder*" - then just import it in every of those files. Don't use a global variable!

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it, thanks

```html
module.exports.randomStringGenerator = function (){
    return Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 7);
  }
```