# What is ((window) => { ...})(window); meaning

Tags: javascript

I file in a project contains the following code:

```
 //begin of the file
 ((window) => {
    'use strict';
class View extends GSM.EventEmitter {

    constructor() {
        super();
//some function here

}
})(window);
//end of the file
```

- What does this structure mean?
- What is this line for `((window) => {}(window);` ?
- What does `constructor()`mean ?

My English a little poor,hope I make the question clear.:-)

Comment: Is my answer helpful?, or you need more information???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

es6 arrow function, for more detail https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

and class
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 1):

This is Module Pattern written on ES6. It allows you group your variables in the same scope and isolate them from other "modules".

```
(function(/* your deps */){
  //your code
  var privateVariable;
}(/* your dependencies */))
```

You can find more detailed answer about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776940/javascript-module-pattern-with-example).

`constructor` function allows you initialize your class instance.