# i cant change or update the variable with my function

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm trying to create a button that when it clicked it can change the variable that I already declared

here is my simple code but it doesn't seem to work

```
<script>
var a = 1;
function myFunction(a){
  if(a=1){
    alert("the value of a now is" + a);
    a=2
  }else if(a=2){
    alert("the value of a now is" + a);
  }      
}
</script>
```

what I expected to work is that if I run or click the button twice the result will be it alerting me that "the value of a now is 2" but it keeps alerting me "the value of a now is 1"

Comment: `myFunction` has a parameter called `a` which shadows the global variable.

Comment: `a=1` is an assignment (and it resolves to `1`, *truthy*). `a==1` or better `a===1` are comparisons. And yes, assigning a value inside a condition makes is valid JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an assignment operation `=` in the `if()` and `else if()` block do a comparison check using the equality `==` operator:

```
 if(a == 1)
```

And in the else if:

```
else if(a == 2)
```

This is why you always get the output:

> "the value of a now is 1"

As the value of 1 is repeatedly assigned to `a` when you invoke the function.

Also you would lose access to the local variable `a` inside the function after you assign in the `if` block to the value 2, later when you execute the function again you would check the new local variable.

In order to prevent this do not use a local variable in the function parameter, just access the global `a`.

```
var a = 1;
function myFunction(){
  if(a == 1){
    alert("the value of a now is" + a);
    a = 2;
  }else if(a == 2){
    alert("the value of a now is" + a);
  }      
}
```

You can also use the [**module pattern**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776940/javascript-module-pattern-with-example) to prevent the pollution of the global namespace with unnecessary variables.

```js
var handler = (function myFunction(){
  var a = 1;
  return function(){
    if(a == 1){
      alert("the value of a now is" + a);
      a = 2;
    }else if(a == 2){
      alert("the value of a now is" + a);
    }
  };
})();
```

```html
<button onclick="handler()" id="myButton">Click</button>
```

Comment: @fredricksutandy glad to help, please mark the answer which you found to be useful as accepted

Answer (score 0):

When you use `a` as a function parameter, you access a local variable `a` rather than your global `a`.

Do one of the following:

```js
var a = 1;

// myFunction uses global 'a'
function myFunction(){
  if(a=1){
    alert("the value of a now is" + a);
    a=2
  }else if(a=2){
    alert("the value of a now is" + a);
  }      
}
```

```js
var a = 1;

// myFunction takes a variable
function myFunction(a){
  if(a=1){
    alert("the value of a now is" + a);
    a=2
  }else if(a=2){
    alert("the value of a now is" + a);
  }      
}

// myFunction is passed global 'a'
myFunction(a);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering my question, I tried your code but the second time I clicked it doesn't alert the "the value of a now is 2"  thank you.

Comment: Did you fix the other problem that was pointed out by @AmardeepBhowmick?